# Issues with Chrome for Android Left Click event mouse

Tags: android, google-chrome, mouseevent

We had a drawing app using webview, and work fine with Android 6.0 and 7.0, with Chrome version 56.0.2924.87 and Bluetooth mouse, but after Chrome update to 58.0.3029.83, the left click event don't trigger.
I tested open draw app directly from Chrome (or using any other tool to draw online, like sketch.io) and found the same issue.

Could it be a new setting? Or if a bug, how downgrade Chrome from Android.

**[Added]**

I just made a simple example that what happen:

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dogerigoca/edit?html,output)

When you use Chrome for Android last version 56.0.2924.87, this work fine (show on yellow color) click event and keep click and move the mouse. But when you open this page via Webview (using for example [Webview Developer Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webviewbrowser)) and do the same, only click is a trigger, and not mousemove event.

Code used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
        <style>

            .canvas{
               width: 500px;
               height: 300px;
               border-style: double;
            }

            .mini-box{
               width: 30px;
               height: 20px;
               border: solid;
               border-width: 1px;
               float: left;
               text-align: center;
            }

         </style>
     <script language='JavaScript'>

         var mc, mm, mu, md, ts, tm, te, tc;

         function reset_box(boxName){
             var oBox = document.getElementById(boxName);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
         }

         function click_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'mc';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(mc);
             mc = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function mousemove_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'mm';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(mm);
             mm = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function mouseup_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'mu';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(mu);
             mu = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function mousedown_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'md';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(md);
             md = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function touchstart_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'ts';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(ts);
             ts = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function touchmove_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'tm';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(tm);
             tm = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function touchend_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'te';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(te);
             te = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function touchcancel_on_canvas(){
             var sId = 'tc';
             var oBox = document.getElementById(sId);
             oBox.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
             clearTimeout(tc);
             tc = setTimeout('reset_box("' + sId + '")', 1000);
         }

         function prepareCanvas(){
             oContext.strokeRect(0, 0, oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height);
             with (oCanvas){
                 addEventListener('click', click_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('contextmenu', click_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart_on_canvas,false);
                 addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('touchleave', touchend_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('touchend', touchend_on_canvas, false);
                 addEventListener('touchcancel', touchcancel_on_canvas, false);
         }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='surface' class='canvas'>This browser can not handle HML5</canvas>
    <br />
    <div id='md' class='mini-box'>md</div>
    <div id='mm' class='mini-box'>mm</div>
    <div id='mu' class='mini-box'>mu</div>
    <div id='mc' class='mini-box'>mc</div>
    <div id='mx' class='mini-box'>mx</div>
    <div id='ts' class='mini-box'>ts</div>
    <div id='tm' class='mini-box'>tm</div>
    <div id='te' class='mini-box'>te</div>
    <div id='tc' class='mini-box'>tc</div>
    <script language='JavaScript'>

        var oCanvas = document.getElementById('surface');
        var oContext = oCanvas.getContext('2d');
        prepareCanvas();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having users that are using a bluetooth or OTG mouse in the Android webview complaining that mouse clicks are being registered as long presses.

Comment: All mouse clicks are not registered (even in the Chrome browser). You can't click on any web content on Samsung devices with Android 6.0.1 and WebView version 58.0.3029.83. I've also tested it on a Sony device and there is no problem. It's a Samsung specific problem with Android 6.0.1 and the latest webview (it works on Android 7.0 and higher)